# "Page not found" when a user clicks on a Facebook invite from my application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm not sure if this is a programming related problem or not, but as I have no experience with the Facebook SDK I'm just assuming that I did something wrong somewhere, even though I've followed the documentation to the `T`.

I am using the Unity SDK for anybody that is curious, and I am using the [FB.AppRequest](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Apprequest) to send the invite to the application, the code in my application looks exactly like that in the documentation.

```
public void InviteFriends() {
        FB.AppRequest(
            message: "Come play this great game!", 
            callback: LogCallback
        );
}

void LogCallback(FBResult result) {
    Debug.Log("Callback was called: " + result.Text);
}
```

This brings up the box as expected and allows me to invite a friend, and the friend does get the invite, however once they click on the invite they are redirected to a page that looks like this:

[image]

Which is causing quite a bit of problems for me; I've checked everything in the application panel and it seems like everything checks out. My google play identifier is correct as-well as my Class Name. My key hashes are all correct. I don't know what else I can do. If you'd like to look up my bundle identifier on the play store it's `buzz.qualify` and I'm sure that you'll find it with ease.

I should also add that I have an application page which can be found here: https://www.facebook.com/pages/Qualify/1647231425506903?fref=ts

This page is linked to the facebook application in the developer console as-well.

What can I do to resolve this issue? Is it in the code? Please help, this has been a 4 day long set-back and we're losing progress rapidly because of it.

It's been a few days now, we're now paying someone for a fix through paypal.

Comment: facebook-graph-api is a relevant tag. I meant `unity` tag, that has nothing to do with Unity game engine.

Comment: Have you set up a public facebook page for your application?

Comment: @MaxYankov - The fact that I'm using the Unity game engine and the Unity SDK makes it relevant, does it not? and yes I have.

Comment: @MaxYankov - The tag used it `unity3d` and only explains what `unity` is, i still feel that it's relevant to the question. As for the page, yes I have it set up and linked in the development panel.

Comment: The tag is `unity3d` right now, because I edited the question. Originally it was `unity` tag, that is about something else. If you read the description of `unity` tag, you would see that the first thing there is a warning not to use it for questions related to Unity game engine.

Comment: @MaxYankov - My apologies, I did not notice that it was changed.

Comment: I understand that it seems like I'm getting mad about mere details, but there are a lot of users who follow certain tags to answer questions. And having an incorrect tag makes them skip your question, and reduces the probability of your question being answered.

Comment: @MaxYankov - I understand, I was just under the impression that the tag i used was `unity3d` from the beginning. It was just a missunderstanding on my part.

Comment: I believe this has to be with your Facebook App settings. Have you enabled Unity integration? Also, if you're deploying your Unity game on iOS or Android, you have to add that to your Facebook settings (bundle ID, package name, etc...). It looks like Facebook is trying to redirect to the Unity web page (which hasn't been added to the settings). I hope it helps.

Comment: JavierdelaCueva -Facebook doesn't even have a "Unity integration" toggle.

@HemantDubey - I resolved the issue by rewriting my application structure. Basically started from the ground up with only a facebook integration, took like 3 days to rewrite the app, but was worth it.

southerton - and you're just spamming.

Comment: Dude, go out of debug and release a production APK or add your debug keyhash to fb.

Comment: @MananMerevikSharma - Your comment is incorrect, and highly delayed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Canvas App setup on Facebook for your Android Game?

If not, read 
[Requirements for Invitable Friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.4).

It states that your game request will...

> direct recipients to one of the following places:
>
> 1. Your app on Facebook Canvas.
> 2. Your native app on iOS or Android, if installed.
> 3. The Apple App Store or Google Play, if not installed.